# what is the difference between 'comm' file and 'cmdline' file in a /proc/<pid> directory?

Tags: linux, proc

Read the docs, couldn't really figure out what is the difference.
It seems like `cmdline` is just the absolute path to the process binary and `comm` is just the name of the binary
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*/proc/pid/cmdline*

> This  read-only file holds the complete command line for the process

It is the *complete command line*. If your command is `ls -l /tmp`, then this file will hold `ls -l /tmp` (separated by null characters, not spaces).

*/proc/pid/comm*

> This  file exposes the process's comm value—that is, the command name associated with the process.  Different threads in the same process may have different comm values, accessible via /proc/pid/task/tid/comm.  A thread may  modify  its  comm  value

This field typically starts as the filename of the executable truncated to some 15 chars or so, but it can be changed to anything by the process itself.